# How to write JS function foo(baz) where baz is: function baz(para){alert(para.data);}

Tags: javascript

I encountered this code; and I curiously tried to write a similar code structure. I am **NOT** taking about **Geolocation**.

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getPosition);

    function getPosition(position) 
    {
      alert(position.coords.latitude);
    }
```

How to write some function like `getCurrentPosition` that accepts a function with a parameter `getPosition(position)` and assigning object to the parameter `position` so that it is possible to read its properties like in `position.coords.latitude`

How to write a similar structure?
And, is it possible to write `getPosition(position)` so that it returns like this:

```
function getPosition(position) 
{
  return position.coords.latitude;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what we call a `callback`:

```js
function funcOne(callback) {
    /* Do some stuff */
    console.log('funcOne');
    // Execute the callback
    callback();
}

function funcTwo() {
  /* Do some more stuff */
  console.log('funcTwo');
}

funcOne(funcTwo); // Will execute both functions one after the other
```

```html
<script src="http://www.wzvang.com/snippet/ignore_this_file.js"></script>
```

As for your second question, yes, you can return the result of the second function in the first one. This will output `funcTwo` even though you've never explicitly called it:

```js
function funcOne(callback) {
    return callback(); // Execute the callback, return the result
}

function funcTwo() {
    return 'funcTwo';
}

console.log( funcOne(funcTwo) ); // Outputs 'funcTwo'
```

```html
<script src="http://www.wzvang.com/snippet/ignore_this_file.js"></script>
```

*`console.log` override is courtesy of [wZVanG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074519/wzvang).*

Comment: [Off-topic]: You can try this snippet :P: http://www.wzvang.com/snippet/ignore_this_file.js

Comment: @wZVanG [That's pretty darn good!](http://jsfiddle.net/gwjskx8o/) Do you mind if I use it in the future, for more complex logs (not really needed here)? I'd mention your name of course.

Comment: Just use it, use `console.log`. Credits are not necessary ;)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we are creating an API and its called SuperAPI. This is how we would define it and expose a method called `getCurrentPosition` which gives out a position.

```
var SuperAPI = function(){};
SuperAPI.prototype.getCurrentPosition = function(fn){ // <--- fn will be the function that needs to be executed and parameters need to be sent to it
  var pos = [10,0]; // <--- our API will do some magic and send position as a parameter to the function that is passed to getCurrentPosition
  fn.call(this, pos); // <--- this is responsible to invoke the function sent to getCurrentPosition and pass the parameters *currentPosition*
  return this; // <--- this will enable chaining
};
SuperAPI.prototype.someMoreStuff = function(){
  alert('some more stuff');
};
```

Check [docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more information about call. Apart from call, apply can also be used to set context and send parameters.

On the client side this is how we consume it.

```
var myapi = new SuperAPI();
myapi.getCurrentPosition(function(currentPosition){
  // currentPosition will be [10,0]
  alert(currentPosition[0] + ':' + currentPosition[1]); 
}).someMoreStuff();
```

```js
var SuperAPI = function() {};
SuperAPI.prototype.getCurrentPosition = function(fn) {
  var pos = [10, 0];
  fn.call(this, pos);
  return this;
};
SuperAPI.prototype.someMoreStuff = function() {
  alert('some more stuff');
};


var myapi = new SuperAPI();
myapi.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  alert(pos[0] + ':' + pos[1]);
}).someMoreStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following this example, you can pass a callback function:

```js
var myObj = {
  bar: {x: 100, y:200},
  foo: function(baz){
    return baz(this.bar);
  }
}

myObj.foo(function(position){
  console.log(position);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://www.wzvang.com/snippet/ignore_this_file.js?theme=default"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
function foo(callback) {
    var data = {};
    // here some code that fills the variable with some real values
    callback(data); // calls the passed function with the data object
};

foo(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Basically the passed function is invoked somewhere in the code of foo.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking about the callback function pattern and there are plenty of sources to read about [them](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+callback+function+pattern). As for the last part of your question, technically *yes* but it won't be assigned to anything if it is an async operation.

For example:

```js
function doSomethingSync(f) {
  return f('FOO');
}

function doSomethingAsync(f) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    return f('BAR');
  }, 0);
}

function returnVal(val) {
  return val;
}

var foo = doSomethingSync(returnVal);
var bar = doSomethingAsync(returnVal);

document.write('<pre>foo === ' + foo + '</pre><pre>bar === ' + bar + '</pre>');
```